# Nested input disappears when upgrading to activeadmin 1.0

Tags: activeadmin, nested-forms, rails-upgrade

I have a form that, when maximally simplified, looks like this.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo do
  form do |f1|
    f1.inputs 'DeepFoos' do
      f1.has_many :deep_foos do |f2|
        f2.input :name

        f2.inputs "DeeperFoos for #{f2.object.name}" do
          f2.has_many :deeper_foos do |f3|
            f3.input :color
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I was using activeadmin `0.6.6`, this rendered fine, with the double-nested resource. After updating to `1.0.0.pre5`, the `DeeperFoos` input part of the form disappeared. There's no exception, and it's not in the html source code of the page. It's simply gone.

Weirdly, if I remove the line that says `f2.input :name`, the `DeeperFoos` input rendered again.

I tried putting a debugger in it, and the debugger is hit, but the gem is so indirect and metaprogrammed that I don't know how I could possibly gain insight from it.

I can't find anything relevant in the [activeadmin upgrade docs](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Upgrading-ActiveAdmin) or the [formtastic upgrade docs](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/Upgrading-to-Formtastic-3.1) (which, as a dependency, got upgraded from `2.2.1` to `3.1.5`).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the [rewrite to integrate Arbre into forms](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3486).  You are welcome to open a [forms issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aforms) but I've given up for now on patching together Arbre, Formtasic and ActionView: as you have discovered it's ugly as they don't always share the same output buffers.  ASFAIK relatively few try to use [nested has_many](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/0c342275cd90455ddf6b2787e7a3c3e00bfdaa69/spec/unit/form_builder_spec.rb#L898).  Can you move the input below inputs? Remove the blank line? It may just be a case of fiddling around and taking the best compromise.